# Butter Knife return null pointer

Tags: android, butterknife

I want to using Butter Knife in my project.I did everything according to the Butter Knife tutorial.
But when I set anything to the views (setText, setClickListener ...) I got null object reference exception.

This is my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginView, View.OnClickListener {

@BindView(R.id.acEtUsername) AppCompatEditText userName;
@BindView(R.id.acEtPassword) AppCompatEditText password;
@BindView(R.id.prgCheckLogin) ProgressBar prgCheckLogin;
@BindView(R.id.btnLogin) Button btnLogin;

LoginPresenter loginPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);

    loginPresenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(this);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this); // or userName.setText("userName");
  }
  /** Other Methods **/
```

activity_login.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/acEtUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/acEtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="@string/login"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgCheckLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And error log

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

What's wrong in my code ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide `activity_login.xml`?

Comment: Can you post the error log too

Comment: @nhaarman activity_login.xml Added

Comment: Where are you calling `setText`? Looks like you're invoking the method before binding the view

Comment: @AgileNinja after binding butter knife, in onCreate method

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I fixed it.

There is a problem with my build.gradle

I forgot to add

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

to the build.gradle

Thank everyone

**UPDATE**

If you are using `neenbedankt.android-apt` plugin first remove it.

Then remove `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'`

And then add `annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'`
 to the dependencies.

**UPDATE 2**

If you are using kotlin replace :

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

with:

```
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

And don't forget to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

after:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: How your ran in the first place without dependency

Comment: This is my third time here.Facepalm

Answer (score 17):

In your `onCreate` method, make sure you have the line:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Without that line, the binds you set up aren't performed, and the views remain null.

Answer (score 12):

Use the following if your are using the new [Butter Knife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/README.md#download) version:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

> If you are using **Kotlin**, replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`.

**UPDATE:**

If you are using Gradle plugin 3.0 or above in your project, change `compile` to `implementation`. like below:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Comment: @MaximeClaude If you are using Kotlin, replace annotationProcessor with kapt. Also make sure you add both lines.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Darush. I just discovered that the problem is that I use it out of an/a activity/fragment. I pass a view to a constructor of that class and try to bind it there. Maybe this is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Darush thank you, I replaced the annotationProcessor with kapt and it worked for me.

Comment: Remember add this line in onCreateView: ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);

Comment: I don't understand the class where I got null view is Java, just some of my classes are written in Kotlin. "Replace annotationProcessor with kapt" works, however.

Answer (score 3):

I started getting NPE errors when, on an existing project, I added support for DataBinding and Kotlin.

I had:

`annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:x.x.x'`

..and replaced with:

`kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:x.x.x"`

Answer (score 2):

Yep, Butterknife by Jake Wharton has been updated to 8.0.1

Please refer at his git account for steps [Butterknife Git](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

On final note : 
Make sure the line apply plugin ... is placed somewhere at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception. In my case I forgot to add `jcenter()` repository in my app-module `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        //this was missed
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```