# ButterKnife issues in android

Tags: android, butterknife, android-mvp

I am using `butterknife` with `retrofit`. when I load fragment continiously with network call my fragment crashes with null pointer on views. I have implemented unbind in `onDestroyView()` in fragment...?

I am not getting error while doing the same thing using `findviewbyid`. Iam using MVP .

```
Unbinder unbinder;
@BindView(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout)
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

@BindView(R.id.recycler_view_shop)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@BindView(R.id.ll_content)
LinearLayout layoutContent;

@BindView(R.id.ll_no_data)
LinearLayout layoutNoData;

@BindView(R.id.tv_category_heading)
TextView categoryHeading;

private HomeActivity activity;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
DrListFragmentPresenter presenter;


public DrListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dr, container, false);
    // bind view using butter knife
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getFragment().getActivity(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    activity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();

    presenter = new DrListFragmentPresenterImpl(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public Fragment getFragment() {
    return this;
}


@Override
public void setCategoriesDetailsAdapter(CategoryWiseItemListingAdapter adapter) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}





@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    // unbind the view to free some memory
    unbinder.unbind();
}    

}
```

Comment: Could you post your gradle? and your error log

Comment: give your adapter full code.

Comment: Add the error log

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception of basic vies in that fragment. now i am getting null pointer on swipe refresh layout. if i bind  vie with findviewbyId its worrking fine

Answer (score 0):

**Check `project gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    // add this in your code
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'  
}
```

**Check `app gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'  // add this 

...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    // add this 
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0
}
```

### And in the version `8.8.1`

**You can add this in `app gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
...
dependencies {
     compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
     annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

**And add this in `project gradle`**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
    }
}
```

And you can check

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: It's not necessary to add apt 'com.....' to the gradle file. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925765/butter-knife-return-null-pointer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer .But in my code , I add this and worked well .And in the new version ,it will add another .

Comment: Yes, probably you are using an old version of the butterknife.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the following scenario:

1. open fragment A
2. open fragment B (quickly, before the data in
   fragment A appears)
3. reopen fragment A

When opening fragment A for the first time, retrofit calls the API, before the call is complete, moves to fragment B, then fragment A will be called `onDestroyView`. In this method butterknife is `unbinded`. When returning to fragment A, the response process from the API is called, now the component is null because it has been unbinded.

**Solution**: Canceled the request when moving to fragment B (onDestroyView) using `call.cancel()`

```
private Call call;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dr, container, false);
    // bind view using butter knife
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    call = downloadService.downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(fileUrl);
    call.enqueue(){
        // error occured here
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    // unbind the view to free some memory
    unbinder.unbind();

    // cancel request
    call.cancel();
}
```