# 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Hi experts I am new to android studio and currently watching tutorials. Right now I encountered

**'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference**

error even after following the tutorial. I've also searched for same issue and found that this can be solved by initializing the recyclerview and providing the right layout name. I'm pretty sure I've met both solution but I am still facing the same issue. Please guide me on this.

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.cart;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.example.cart.adapter.MyProductAdapter;
import com.example.cart.listener.CartLoadListener;
import com.example.cart.listener.ProductLoadListener;
import com.example.cart.model.CartModel;
import com.example.cart.model.ProductModel;
import com.example.cart.utils.SpaceItemDecoration;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProductLoadListener, CartLoadListener {
    @BindView(R.id.rv)
    RecyclerView rviewer;
    @BindView(R.id.mainLayout)
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.badge)
    NotificationBadge badge;
    @BindView(R.id.btnCart)
    FrameLayout btnCart;
    @BindView(R.id.search)
    SearchView search;

    ProductLoadListener productLoadListener;
    CartLoadListener cartLoadListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        loadProductFromFirebase();
    }

    private void loadProductFromFirebase() {
        List<ProductModel> productModels = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("product")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists()) {
                            for(DataSnapshot productSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                                ProductModel productModel = productSnapshot.getValue(ProductModel.class);
                                productModel.setKey(productSnapshot.getKey());
                                productModels.add(productModel);

                            }
                            productLoadListener.onProductLoadSuccess(productModels);
                        } else {
                            productLoadListener.onProductLoadFail("Can't Find Product");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        productLoadListener.onProductLoadFail(error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void init() {
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        productLoadListener = this;
        cartLoadListener = this;

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        rviewer.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        rviewer.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductLoadSuccess(List<ProductModel> productModelList) {
        MyProductAdapter adapter = new MyProductAdapter(this, productModelList);
        rviewer.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductLoadFail(String message) {
        Snackbar.make(mainLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCartLoadSuccess(List<CartModel> cartModelList) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCartLoadFail(String message) {

    }
}
```

**MyProductAdapter.java**

```java
package com.example.cart.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.cart.R;
import com.example.cart.model.ProductModel;
import com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.Unbinder;

public class MyProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyProductAdapter.MyProductViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ProductModel> productModelList;

    public MyProductAdapter(Context context, List<ProductModel> productModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productModelList = productModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyProductViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(productModelList.get(position).getImage())
                .into(holder.img1);
        holder.productPrice.setText(new StringBuilder("$").append(productModelList.get(position).getPrice()));
        holder.productName.setText(new StringBuilder().append(productModelList.get(position).getName()));
        holder.productDescription.setText(new StringBuilder().append(productModelList.get(position).getDescription()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productModelList.size();
    }

    public class MyProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.img1)
        RoundedImageView img1;
        @BindView(R.id.productName)
        TextView productName;
        @BindView(R.id.productDescription)
        TextView productDescription;
        @BindView(R.id.productPrice)
        TextView productPrice;

        private Unbinder unbinder;

        public MyProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3BE838"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchCartLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="16"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnCart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24" />

            <com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge
                android:id="@+id/badge"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:nbMaxTextLength="2"/>
        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breadCrumb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_view"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="  App/Page name : Products / Services"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="750dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/breadCrumb"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The specific error is because `rviewer` is null in `init`. Maybe ButterKnife isn't set up correctly in the project so the view doesn't get bound? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925765/butter-knife-return-null-pointer) or [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/README.md#download) and make sure you added the `annotationProcessor` line in gradle too.

Comment: Hi @TylerV, thanks for answering the question! it appears that I'm lacking with the ```annotationprocessor
```. This solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds good - it seems like the same issue as [Butter Knife return null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925765/butter-knife-return-null-pointer) then so I'll mark it as a duplicate.